# How can I set an NSDate object to midnight?

Tags: ios, datetime, swift, nsdate, nscalendar

I have an `NSDate` object and I want to set it to an arbitrary time (say, midnight) so that I can use the `timeIntervalSince1970` function to retrieve data consistently without worrying about the time *when* the object is created.

I've tried using an `NSCalendar` and modifying its components by using some Objective-C methods, like this:

```swift
let date: NSDate = NSDate()
let cal: NSCalendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSGregorianCalendar)!

let components: NSDateComponents = cal.components(NSCalendarUnit./* a unit of time */CalendarUnit, fromDate: date)
let newDate: NSDate = cal.dateFromComponents(components)
```

The problem with the above method is that you can only set one unit of time (`/* a unit of time */`), so you could only have one of the following be accurate:

1. Day
2. Month
3. Year
4. Hours
5. Minutes
6. Seconds

Is there a way to set hours, minutes, and seconds at the same time and retain the date (day/month/year)?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Your statement

> The problem with the above method is that you can only set one unit of
>   time ...

is not correct. `NSCalendarUnit` conforms to the `RawOptionSetType` protocol which 
inherits from `BitwiseOperationsType`. This means that the options can be bitwise
combined with `&` and `|`.

In **Swift 2 (Xcode 7)** this was changed again to be
an `OptionSetType` which offers a set-like interface, see
for example [Error combining NSCalendarUnit with OR (pipe) in Swift 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32381664/error-combining-nscalendarunit-with-or-pipe-in-swift-2-0).

Therefore the following compiles and works in iOS 7 and iOS 8:

```
let date = NSDate()
let cal = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)!

// Swift 1.2:
let components = cal.components(.CalendarUnitDay | .CalendarUnitMonth | .CalendarUnitYear, fromDate: date)
// Swift 2:
let components = cal.components([.Day , .Month, .Year ], fromDate: date)

let newDate = cal.dateFromComponents(components)
```

(Note that I have omitted the type annotations for the variables, the Swift compiler
infers the type automatically from the expression on the right hand side of
the assignments.)

Determining the start of the given day (midnight) can also done 
with the `rangeOfUnit()` method (iOS 7 and iOS 8):

```
let date = NSDate()
let cal = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)!
var newDate : NSDate?

// Swift 1.2:
cal.rangeOfUnit(.CalendarUnitDay, startDate: &newDate, interval: nil, forDate: date)
// Swift 2:
cal.rangeOfUnit(.Day, startDate: &newDate, interval: nil, forDate: date)
```

*If* your deployment target is iOS 8 then it is even simpler:

```
let date = NSDate()
let cal = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)!
let newDate = cal.startOfDayForDate(date)
```

---

Update for **Swift 3 (Xcode 8):**

```
let date = Date()
let cal = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
let newDate = cal.startOfDay(for: date)
```

Comment: It's strange that the `startOfDayForDate:` method is undocumented although it is exposed in the header file among with a lot of new methods also undocumented. Thanks for this.

Comment: @Desdenova: It is also listed in the [iOS 8.0 API Diffs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/iOS80APIDiffs/frameworks/Foundation.html), but you are right, the `NSCalendar` documentation is indeed not up to date.

Comment: I knew that there was something I was missing. Thanks; this is what I needed.

Comment: @Desdenova The same is true for the `dateBySettingHour` method.

Comment: Be careful using `startOfDayForDate()`, because it works right only in UTC locale.

Comment: @adnako: I am pretty sure that startOfDayForDate works correctly in all time zones. Do you have a concrete example?

Comment: @MartinR My time zone is UTC+3, value is '2016-06-28 15:35:44 UTC', if I call startOfDayForDate on this date the result is '2016-06-27 21:00:00 UTC'. It's not exactly what I need.

Comment: @adnako: Note that '2016-06-27 21:00:00 UTC' is '2016-06-28 00:00:00' in your time zone, so the result is correct. To *print* the result according to your time zone you need an NSDateFormatter.

Comment: @MartinR I did say that user should consider that function works as expected in UTC time zone.

Answer (score 38):

Yes.

You don't need to fiddle with the components of the `NSCalendar` at all; you can simply call the `dateBySettingHour` method and use the `ofDate` parameter with your existing date.

```
let date: NSDate = NSDate()
let cal: NSCalendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSGregorianCalendar)!

let newDate: NSDate = cal.dateBySettingHour(0, minute: 0, second: 0, ofDate: date, options: NSCalendarOptions())!
```

For Swift 3:

```
let date: Date = Date()
let cal: Calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)

let newDate: Date = cal.date(bySettingHour: 0, minute: 0, second: 0, of: date)!
```

Then, to get your time since 1970, you can just do

```
let time: NSTimeInterval = newDate.timeIntervalSince1970
```

`dateBySettingHour` was introduced in OS X Mavericks (10.9) and gained iOS support with iOS 8.

Declaration in `NSCalendar.h`:

```
/*
    This API returns a new NSDate object representing the date calculated by setting hour, minute, and second to a given time.
    If no such time exists, the next available time is returned (which could, for example, be in a different day than the nominal target date).
    The intent is to return a date on the same day as the original date argument.  This may result in a date which is earlier than the given date, of course.
 */
- (NSDate *)dateBySettingHour:(NSInteger)h minute:(NSInteger)m second:(NSInteger)s ofDate:(NSDate *)date options:(NSCalendarOptions)opts NS_AVAILABLE(10_9, 8_0);
```

Comment: Me no see documentation https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/index.html

Comment: @SantaClaus It doesn't appear to be in the formal docs, but it makes an appearance in [this session](http://asciiwwdc.com/2013/sessions/227) from WWDC 2013 and in the `NSCalendar.h` file. It's supported in OS X 10.9+ and iOS 8.

Comment: very important to note that it requires ios 8 then

Comment: How to achieve the same in iOS7?

Comment: You shouldn't force unwrap. If you try to set some dates to midnight it might return nil because of daylight savings time offset

Comment: This method `dateBySettingHour` not exist for me in NSDate

Comment: @jose920405 that's because it's a method of the NSCalendar class.

Comment: 'NSGregorianCalendar' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 8.0 - Use NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian instead

Comment: should be `let cal: NSCalendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)!`

Answer (score 8):

Here's an example of how you would do it, without using the `dateBySettingHour` function  (to make sure your code is still compatible with iOS 7 devices):

```
NSDate* now = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [gregorian components:(NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit) fromDate:now];
NSDate* midnightLastNight = [gregorian dateFromComponents:dateComponents];
```

Yuck.

There is a reason why I prefer coding in C#...

Anyone fancy some readable code..?

```
DateTime midnightLastNight = DateTime.Today;
```

;-)

Comment: I wish dates were as easy to work with in Swift as C# :(.

Answer (score 5):

**Swift** **iOS 8 and up**: People tend to forget that the Calendar and DateFormatter objects have a TimeZone. If you do not set the desired timzone and the default timezone value is not ok for you, then the resulting hours and minutes could be off.

**Note:** In a real app you could optimize this code some more.

**Note:** When not caring about timezones, the results could be OK on one device, and bad on an other device just because of different timezone settings.

**Note:** Be sure to add an existing timezone identifier! This code does not handle a missing or misspelled timezone name.

```
func dateTodayZeroHour() -> Date {
    var cal = Calendar.current
    cal.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "Europe/Paris")!
    return cal.startOfDay(for: Date())   
}
```

You could even extend the language. If the default timezone is fine for you, do not set it.

```
extension Date {
    var midnight: Date {
        var cal = Calendar.current
        cal.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "Europe/Paris")!
        return cal.startOfDay(for: self)
    }
    var midday: Date {
        var cal = Calendar.current
        cal.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "Europe/Paris")!
        return cal.date(byAdding: .hour, value: 12, to: self.midnight)!
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "Europe/Paris")
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"

let midnight = Date().midnight
let midnightString = formatter.string(from: midnight)
let midday = Date().midday
let middayString = formatter.string(from: midday)

let wheneverMidnight = formatter.date(from: "2018/12/05 08:08:08")!.midnight
let wheneverMidnightString = formatter.string(from: wheneverMidnight)

print("dates: \(midnightString) \(middayString) \(wheneverMidnightString)")
```

The string conversions and the DateFormatter are needed in our case for some formatting and to move the timezone since the date object in itself does not keep or care about a timezone value.

**Watch out!** The resulting value could differ because of a timezone offset somewhere in your calculating chain!

Comment: value= 12 is incorrect. Use : symbol like in any other method parameter

Answer (score 5):

**Swift 5+**

```
let date = Calendar.current.date(bySettingHour: 0, minute: 0, second: 0, of: Date())
```

Comment: This will return the zero hour relative to timezone.

Comment: The output is not 00:00:00

Answer (score 2):

Just in case someone is looking for this:

Using [SwiftDate](https://github.com/malcommac/SwiftDate) you could just do this:

```
Date().atTime(hour: 0, minute: 0, second: 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the solution, which is easiest to verify, but perhaps not the quickest, is to use strings.

```
func set( hours: Int, minutes: Int, seconds: Int, ofDate date: Date ) -> Date {

    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

    let newDateString = "\(dateFormatter.string(from: date)) \(hours):\(minutes):\(seconds)"

    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

    return dateFormatter.date(from: newDateString)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func resetHourMinuteSecond(date: NSDate, hour: Int, minute: Int, second: Int) -> NSDate{
    let nsdate = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateBySettingHour(hour, minute: minute, second: second, ofDate: date, options: NSCalendarOptions(rawValue: 0))
    return nsdate!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the current calendar to get the start of the day for the current time.

```swift
let today = Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: Date())
```