# Swift : Parse, query date field based on nsdate()

Tags: swift, parse-platform

i am trying to retrieve records which were added today to parse, but the query does not return any results. how can i get the query to return the results based on todays date.

```
let now = NSDate()
var query = PFQuery(className:"userBids")
    query.whereKey("date", equalTo: now)
```

the parse date field is set to date. please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that `NSDate` is not just a date, it's an exact moment in time.

And you're very likely to have exactly *no* records from this precise date and moment in time.

What you should be doing is something like:

```
let now = NSDate()
let cal = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSGregorianCalendar)
let midnightOfToday = cal.startOfDayForDate(now)
var query = PFQuery(className:"userBids")
    query.whereKey("date", greaterThanOrEqualTo: midnightOfToday)
```

The above solution only works for iOS 8 & newer ([and I found it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26189656/how-can-i-set-an-nsdate-object-to-midnight)).  Click on that link if you want to get something that's iOS 7 compatible.

Comment: Using this method how did you get the current date from NSDate()? Not just midnight?