# How to fetch data using nsdate from parse

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, nsdate

I am trying to retrieve records which were added today to parse, but the query does not return any results, I tried with below code,

```
let date = NSDate()
let calendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)
let Today = calendar!.startOfDayForDate(date)

query.whereKey("createdAt", equalTo: Today)
```

can anyone help me please?

Comment: The key that you created was it exactly at 12:00 am? otherwise I don't think it will not match.

Comment: no ! how can i fix it?

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31379063/swift-parse-query-date-field-based-on-nsdate

Answer (score 1):

With `equalTo`, you're just querying objects created at exactly 12:00am.
You should query the range of dates from the 12:00am of today till 12:00am of tomorrow.

Use Parse's `lessThanOrEqualTo` and `greaterThanOrEqualTo`.

```
let date = NSDate()
let calendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)

let today = calendar!.startOfDayForDate(date)

// calculate tomorrow
date = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit(
                   .CalendarUnitDay, 
                   value: 1, 
                   toDate: date, 
                   options: NSCalendarOptions(0))

let tomorrow = calendar!.startOfDayForDate(date)

query.whereKey("createdAt", greaterThanOrEqualTo:today)
query.whereKey("createdAt", lessThanOrEqualTo:tomorrow)
```