# Error combining NSCalendarUnit with OR (pipe) in Swift 2.0

Tags: swift, nsdateformatter, swift2, nscalendar, nsdatecomponents

I have some code that's breaking in Swift 2.0:

```
let formatter = NSDateComponentsFormatter()
formatter.allowedUnits = NSCalendarUnit.Year
formatter.allowedUnits |= .Month
formatter.allowedUnits |= .WeekOfMonth 
formatter.allowedUnits |= .Day
formatter.allowedUnits |= .Hour
formatter.allowedUnits |= .Minute
```

I get the error `Binary operator '|=' cannot be applied to 'NSCalenderUnit' operands`.

What's the new way of doing this kinda thing?

Comment: Essentially the same problem (and solution) as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30761996/swift-2-0-binary-operator-cannot-be-applied-to-two-uiusernotificationtype.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`NSCalendarUnit` is an `OptionSetType` in Swift 2, instead of a `RawOptionSetType`. This means that you can't logical-or it anymore. Instead, you can use an array literal representation of it:

```
formatter.allowedUnits = [.Year, .Month, .WeekOfMonth, .Day, .Hour, .Minute]
```