# Dealing with midnight hours NSDate()

Tags: swift, nsdate, nscalendar

I am doing Open /Close status function that checks and compares current time with open hours of the cafeteria. But it is open till midnight. Midnight represents as 0 how do I compare it to 0?
My current code

```
func displayStatusForBrandywine () -> String
    {
        let currentDateTime = NSDate()
        // get the user's calendar
        let userCalendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
        // choose which date and time components are needed
        let requestedComponents: NSCalendarUnit = [
            NSCalendarUnit.Year,
            NSCalendarUnit.Month,
            NSCalendarUnit.Day,
            NSCalendarUnit.Hour,
            NSCalendarUnit.Minute,
            NSCalendarUnit.Weekday
        ]
        let dateTimeComponents = userCalendar.components(requestedComponents, fromDate: currentDateTime)
        var status: String = ""
        // get the components

        if (dateTimeComponents.hour >= 8 && dateTimeComponets.hour <0) //??
        {
            status = "Open"
        }
        else
        {
            status = "Closed"
        }
        return status
    }
```

Comment: Why not swap the `if` with the `else` and use this condition instead `dateTimeComponents.hour < 8 && dateTimeComponets.hour >=0`

Comment: very clever idea! did not think that way. Thank you!!!

Comment: However, to answer your question properly, check out this [stack overflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26189656/5363378)