# Get time with yyyy-MM-dd 00:00:00 +0000

Tags: ios, swift, date, nsdateformatter

How can i get time with   below format -

> yyyy-MM-dd 00:00:00 +0000

currently i am getting

> 2018-04-16 11:27:06 +Greenwich Mean Time

*by below code -*

```
let nowDate = Date()
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT")
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss +zzzz"
print(dateFormatter.string(from: nowDate))
```

The problem is **time offset** i am looking for `00:00:00 +0000`

Comment: You mean to say you want time in yyyy-MM-dd 00:00:00 +0000 in this format.?

Comment: You can use `DateComponents` or `Calendar` to set the Hour/Minutes/Seconds to 0 on `nowDate`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26189656/how-can-i-set-an-nsdate-object-to-midnight For the +0000 check there: http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns

Comment: for additional info see this : http://nsdateformatter.com/

Comment: @Anbu.karthik `let now = Date()
        let caln = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
        let updated = caln.startOfDay(for: now)
        print(updated)//2018-04-15 18:30:00 +0000` why it's not giving with zero offset :(

Comment: try this:   
    func toLocalTime() -> Date {
        let timezone: TimeZone = TimeZone.current
        let seconds: TimeInterval = TimeInterval(timezone.secondsFromGMT())
        return Date(timeInterval: seconds, since: self)
    }

Comment: @Larme `let date: Date = Date()
        let cal: Calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
        let newDate: Date = cal.date(bySettingHour: 0, minute: 0, second: 0, of: date)!
        print(newDate)// it gives 2018-04-15 18:30:00 +0000 instead `00:00:00 +0000`

Comment: "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"